# Update 2 wordpress tables at once

Tags: custom-post-types, wpdb

I'm connecting to a WordPress database using the wpdb class to select the data that I need from wp_posts and then insert in to another wp_posts table in another database.

So if I make changes on one database, the changes will reflect the other databases as well, change once, update everywhere.

I can get posts to insert in to another database when I add it to the main database, when I update the main database posts it updates the other databases however, when I delete a post from the main database, it does not delete from the posts from the other databases.

Please see my code below.
    `I'm connecting to a WordPress database using the wpdb class to select the data that I need from wp_posts and then insert in to another wp_posts table in another database.

So if I make changes on one database, the changes will reflect the other databases. Change once, update everywhere.

I can get posts to insert in to another database, when I update the main database posts it updates the other databases however, when I delete a post from the main database, it does not delete the posts from the other databases.

Please see my code below.

```
<?php
/**
*@package ChandcoPlugin
*/
/*
Plugin Name: Chandco Legal Policies
Plugin URI: http://www.chandco.co.uk/plugin
Description: CH&Co Legal policies
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Raj Chudasama - CH&Co Group
Author URI: http://www.chandco.co.uk/
License: GPL2
Text Domain: chandco-legal-policies
  */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
die;
}

  //create a custom post type for legal Policies
  function create_policies() {
    $labels = array(
      'name'                  => 'Ch&Co Legal Policies',
      'singular_name'         => 'Ch&Co Legal Policy',
      'add_new_item'          => 'Add A New Policy', 'chandco',
      'new_item'              => 'New Policy', 'chandco',
      'edit_item'             => 'Edit Policy', 'chandco',
      'view_item'             => 'View Policy', 'chandco',
      'all_items'             => 'All Policies', 'chandco',
      'add_new'               => 'Add A New Policy', 'chandco'
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Policies' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'policies', $args);
  }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_policies' );

  function get_policies(){
    //Connect to CH&Co DB to pull the legal policies
    global $wpdb;
    $chandcoDB = new wpdb('root', '', 'chandco', 'localhost');
    //Get legal policies
    $legalPolicies = $chandcoDB->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE     post_type='policies'");
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($legalPolicies);
    foreach ($legalPolicies as $policies) {
      $id = $policies->ID;
      $title = $policies->post_title;
      $content = $policies->post_content;
      $guid = $policies->guid;
      //echo $error;


      //check to see if title doesn't already exist
      //prevents duplicate posts from being inserted in to the DB
      $checkTitle =  get_page_by_title($title, OBJECT, 'policies');

          //$global $post;
          //Access the posts table and copy the data
          //FROM CH&Co CPT
          if (empty($checkTitle) ){
            $my_post = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => $content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'policies'
          );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );
      } elseif (!empty($checkTitle) ){
        $my_post = array(
        'ID' =>  $checkTitle->ID,
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'policies'
      );
      wp_update_post( $my_post );
   }
  }
    echo '
      <style tpye="text/css">
        a {
          padding-right:10px;
        }
      </style>
    ';

    //Get PDF policies
    $pdfPolicies = $chandcoDB->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
      ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND meta_key = 'PDF URL Link'");

    //Get the posts from the current CPT
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
      $args = array (
          'post_type' => 'policies',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
      );

      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $query->have_posts() ):
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        ?>
          <a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title()?></a>
        <?php endwhile;
      endif;
      }
    }

    add_action('init', 'get_policies');
```

`

Comment: This all seems super complicated, is there a reason you're duplicating the data like this? Why not just use a multisite install and `switch_to_blog`? Or have 1 site and map multiple domains to it? For this to work as you expect you're going to have to *push* the changes from the main DB to the others, rather than pulling them on the `init` hook ( doing it on `init` is also going to give very poor performance )

Comment: We have 56 websites where we which want to add policies to, so the solution we came up with was to create a plugin and install it on the 56 websites so that when we add/update/delete a policy from the main website, the changes reflect the other websites.

Setting up a multi site would be difficult wouldn't it as the 6 websites are running on a single install?

Comment: Multisite can handle 56 sites fine, wordpress.com is a multisite with millions of sites

Comment: but if I was to update one site, say like a post, would that same post on the other 56 sites be updated?

Comment: No you'd just use `switch_to_blog` to switch to the site with all the policies, make your query, then `restore_current_blog` afterwards, 1 copy of the data, 1 set of posts, displayed multiple times across multiple sites. Or hook into post creation/deletion and use those functions to create/delete the posts on other sites

Comment: can you give me more info on the post creation/deletion method please. Thanks

Comment: eh that would be quite an involved answer, you're better off breaking it down and asking multiple questions, e.g. how to hook into post saves, how to hook into post deletions, how to contact another site, etc